# How to make it so that Embedded Kafka Rule, doesn't shows data produced from both tests

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to set up an Integration test in Junit. It is utilizing Kafka for Spring, and it's EmbeddedKafkaRule.

I have two tests in the Junit, each one will produce different sets of data.

However, I have noticed when reading both tests in the Idea IDE, I see the first test run with only the first test's data, but the second test running with both the first and second's data. This happens regardless of what order the test is, and does not happen when running each individually.

Here is the configuration he have done when setting up the embedded kafka rule.

```java
private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> producer;

public static final String TEST_TOPIC = "test-topic";

KafkaMessageListenerContainer container;

    @ClassRule
    public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true,
        TEST_TOPIC);
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Object> records;


@Before
public void setupKafka(){
    Map<String, Object> senderProps = KafkaTestUtils.producerProps(embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka());
    ProducerFactory<Integer, String> pf = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Integer, String>(senderProps);
    producer = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);

    producer.setDefaultTopic(TEST_TOPIC);

    waitForConsumerToStart();
}

private void waitForConsumerToStart() {

    Map<String, Object> consumerProperties =
        KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps("test", "false",
            embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka());
    // create a Kafka consumer factory
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory =
        new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String>(
            consumerProperties);
    // set the topic that needs to be consumed
    ContainerProperties containerProperties =
        new ContainerProperties(TEST_TOPIC);

    // create a Kafka MessageListenerContainer
    container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory,
        containerProperties);

    // create a thread safe queue to store the received message
    records = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    // setup a Kafka message listener
    container
        .setupMessageListener(new MessageListener<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(
                ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
                System.out.println("test-listener received message='{}' " +
                    record.toString());
                records.add(record);
            }
        });

    // start the container and underlying message listener
    container.start();


    // wait until the container has the required number of assigned partitions
    ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(container,
        embeddedKafka.getEmbeddedKafka().getPartitionsPerTopic());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use a different topic for each test

```java
@ClassRule
public static EmbeddedKafkaRule embeddedKafka = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true,
    TEST_TOPIC1, TEST_TOPIC2);
```

Comment: I am using a Class Rule to put in the embedded kafka, this is a static variable.
I forgot to put it in the code above, and have done so.

The embeddedKafka is static variable, I am not familiar with any other way to make an kafka test.

Comment: Simply add multiple topics to the broker and use a different one in each test; see the edit.